# Error when installing ROS Noetic Ubuntu 22.04: 404 Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]

Tags: ubuntu, ros

```
~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Ign:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

please help me to fix this bug, I must to install ROS Noetic for Ubuntu 22.04 sory with bad English :(

Answer (score 0):

ROS Noetic targets Ubuntu 20.04. There is also not a ROS1 distro that targets 22.04, and there never will be as Noetic is the last distro for ROS1. If you have to run on 22.04, you will need to run ROS2 with a distro such as [Humble](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Releases/Release-Humble-Hawksbill.html), otherwise you'll have to downgrade to 20.04 to run Noetic.

Answer (score 0):

One other option to run ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 22.04 is to build it from sources on your own. A step-by-step guide can be found at the post [Building ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 22.04](https://medium.com/@lukas_reisinger/building-ros-noetic-on-ubuntu-22-04-b3ca676c63e7)